# How exactly works the Spring MVC themes support? (some doubts about a proposed concrete example)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I am actually studying the theming support.

So I am working on an example application that have the following characteristics:

1] Into the **src/webapp/resources/css** are defined 3 CSS theme files, respectivelly named: **theme-black.css**, **theme-chocolate.css** and **theme-dafault.css**. So these files represents the CSS settings associated to a theme that have to be chosen by the user.

2] Into the **servlet-context.xml** configuration file that should be the file that configure the MVC support there are defined the following beans related to the theming support:

```
<beans:bean id="themeSource"
    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <beans:property name="basenamePrefix" value="META-INF.theme-" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</beans:bean>


<mvc:interceptors>
    <beans:ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors> 

<beans:bean id="themeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</beans:bean>
```

And into the **META-INF** application folder there are the following 3 properties file related to the previous CSS theme files:

**theme-black.properties**:

```
css=resources/css/theme-black.css
```

**theme-chocolate.properties**:

```
css=resources/css/theme-chocolate.css
```

**theme-default.properties**:

```
css=resources/css/theme-default.css
```

And now I want to understand what these beans exactly does.

From what I have understood, the Spring MVC theming support works in the following way:

The web application have a default theme at the beginning (is it the one named **theme-default.css** by default? So if I use the **theme-default.css** for a theme it is loaded as default theme or am I missing something?)

I need to provide to the user a set of theme from which to choose the theme that he want to use.

When the user choose a theme the application send a **cookie** to the user browser and this cookie contain the information about the chosen theme.

Then, any time that the user make any HTTP request to the application (handled by a controller) there must be something that intercept these request and that read the cookie for the chosen theme identification and then use this theme for the response.

So I think that the previous declared beans works in the following way:

1] The first class is the **theme source**:

```
<beans:bean id="themeSource"
    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <beans:property name="basenamePrefix" value="META-INF.theme-" />
</beans:bean>
```

and take as input parameter a property named **basenamePrefix** that identify the previous properties file that contains the concrete themes path (**theme-black.properties**, **theme-chocolate.properties** and **theme-default.properties**).

So this bean should accomplish the first requirement of the theme support (identify and access to the list of themes)

2] The second class is the **theme interceptor**:

```
<beans:bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</beans:bean>
```

that is a class that I can use to intercept any request made by user and do **pre action** and **post action** and from what I have understand it define the URL parameter name that let the user to change the theme.

So in this example the parameter name is **theme** so when the user call an URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/springchocolatestore/?theme=chocolate
```

it is choosing the **chocolate** theme that is related to the **theme-chocolate.properties** so the **resources/css/theme-chocolate.css** file will be used.

So my doubt is: the preaction is to check the presence of the **?theme=chocolate** in the URL and apply the style?

3] The third bean is the **theme resolver**:

```
<beans:bean id="themeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</beans:bean>
```

So this resolver use **cookie** to identify the chosed theme.

So, for example, if I chose the **chocolate theme** (by the request **http://localhost:8080/springchocolatestore/?theme=chocolate**) the web app send to the browser a cookie that store the information that specify that the chocolate theme have to be used.

Then if I reload again the application the page still use the **chocolate theme** (and not the default theme).

It means that the **CookieThemeResolver** had access to this cookie, read it and use this information to select the theme to use?

So I have the following doubts: this cookie is on my file system and the web application is on a remote application server. How can it access to the cookie on my file system? Where this cookie is into my file system and what is its name ? (I want to open it with text editor to examinate it)

Finally it is also declared this configuration:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <beans:ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

What exactly does this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource
```

Loads properties files from the specified base usually classpath.From spring api docs [ResourceBundleThemeSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/context/support/ResourceBundleThemeSource.html) is a ThemeSource implementation that looks up an individual ResourceBundle per theme. The theme name gets interpreted as ResourceBundle basename, supporting a common basename prefix for all themes.

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor
```

Interceptor that allows for changing the current theme on every request, via a configurable request parameter (default parameter name: "theme").
More information can be found in [spring api docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/theme/ThemeChangeInterceptor.html) as well

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver
```

ThemeResolver implementation that uses a cookie sent back to the user in case of a custom setting, with a fallback to the default theme. This is particularly useful for stateless applications without user sessions.
Again more information [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/theme/CookieThemeResolver.html)

> this cookie is on my file system and the web application is on a remote application server. How can it access to the cookie on my file system? Where this cookie is into my file system and what is its name ?

[What's an HTTP cookie in the first place?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

To check cookies sent by any website use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) if you use Firefox or developer tools if you use chrome